# ls command without (hiding) date and time

Tags: osx, ls, timestamps

I want to know if is possible to make a `ls` recurrent but without date-time... Hiding the time and date shown when the command ls is executed.

I want to do some thing like

```
sudo ls -AlhR / > /Volumes/user/Documents/NotProgram.txt
```

Then, I want to install some program.tar.gz

```
sudo ls -AlhR / > /Volumes/user/Documents/YesProgram.txt
```

Compare results Before and After:

```
diff /Volumes/user/Documents/NotProgram.txt /Volumes/user/Documents/YesProgram.txt
```

But the differences of Date & Time is detected by diff.

Thank you...

Comment: If you just want the names of the files, `find / -print` is much cleaner way to get them instead of using `ls`

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish ?

Comment: Thank you, but I need the size of each file listed.

Comment: I want detect the changes (the files added) made the program installation. using `./configure && make && sudo make install`, not prefix, not special conditions.

Comment: A typical case of [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/233676)... Why don't you ask about your actual problem ?

Comment: No is a problem, is how list the files the current system.

Comment: It is quite a sound question. I also have the same problem, I need to list the user, group, and specially the permissions, to pass them onto diff viewer.

Answer (score 8):

Assuming that your `/bin/ls` is from a relatively recent coreutils, you can use the `--time-style` option to specify an empty style.  For example:

```
ls -Alhr --time-style=+""
```

Will get you the same output san the date and time.

Comment: Thank you... but I get this:    $ ls -Alhr --time-style=+""
ls: illegal option -- -
usage: ls [-ABCFGHLOPRSTUWabcdefghiklmnopqrstuwx1] [file ...]

Comment: On what OS are you running?  What package is supplying your `/bin/ls`?  Can you install coreutils?

Comment: Thank you @Andy-dalton , I discovery that doesn't work in macOS Sierra.

Comment: You can install coreutils on Mac OS, if that's something you'd consider doing to resolve your problem: http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/69332